# Available AudioManager's streams for audio reproduction on Android Devices

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

I'm developing an app (Android) to reproduce alarm Sounds. For this, I'm using the AlarmManager for the sound management. The problem exists on the available audio Streams. The documentation tells that the `STREAM_ALARM` is available since API 1, so in theory every Android Device should have the `STREAM_ALARM`.

When the sound is reproduced on an Android Virtual Device (Pixel 2 API 21 - Android 5.0) everything runs as expected. When the same code runs on an physical device (Galaxy Nexus S4, API 21 - Android 5.0), there's no audio reproduction at all. When I changed the stream to `STREAM_MUSIC`, the sound was reproduced without problems.

My question is: shouldn't all the audio streams be available in every device?